# keycloak-angular login by roles

Tags: angular, keycloak

In my project, I aim to restrict login access to only users with the admin or "x" role in Keycloak. However, currently, all users can log in without encountering any errors. Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this access restriction?

```
login() {
    const desiredRole = 'Admin'; 
    const userRoles = this.keycloak.getUserRoles();

    if (userRoles.includes(desiredRole)) { 
      const isLoggedIn = this.keycloak.isLoggedIn();
      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        this.keycloak.login().then(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        });
      } else {
        console.log('User is already logged in.');
      }
    } else {
      console.log('You do not have permission to log in.');
      alert('You do not have permission to log in.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [`CanActiveGuard`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) or [`CanActiveFn`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateFn) and put it in the angular route depending on your angular version to create an interceptor and check `userRoles` before accessing the route and decide to redirect to `Home` route or not.